# file uploading over IBM LoadBalancer fault in IBM WebSphere cluster

Tags: upload, websphere, load-balancing, suse

I have a WebSphere application cluster on SUSE15 with v9 and java8.

2 load balancer and 4 IHS and 4 WAS. it designs for file uploading.

file uploading through load balancers is very very slow and always failed.

as I investigated, the problem is LB, because if I skip them(Load balancers) and directly connect to IHS or WAS, uploading a file, works as expected.

I couldn't find the reason and related load balancer's config.

does anyone know the reason and the answer?

Comment: Likely culprit is some checksum or segmentation offload is enabled on the adapter. When these features are enabled, the packets are not RFC compliant and get dropped by LB. By design, TCP will resend the packets and after two timeouts, sends the packets without the offload enabled and would then be forwarded by LB.  Ensure anything with segment or checksum offload is disabled for each interface (ethtool -k eth0 | grep ": on"  will show enabled settings).  Settings such as scatter-gather, tcp-segmentation-offload, tx-checksumming, *tso*, *gso* should be disabled to prevent dropped packets.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think so, because all servers have the same config and if there is any wrong config it should occurred on all servers. I guessed LBs are guilty because as I told when we test through the IHS everything is OK.

Comment: Since LB would drop packets instead of forwarding when out-of-band data is received or packet checksums are incorrect, why would you think this is not the case ? This has nothing to do with the LB config but is an OS setting. Traffic directly to IHS would have packets handled by OS IP layer and would not have this issue.  Did you check your /var/log/messages for errors reported by LB ? Does your load balancer show increasing counts for number of packets discarded ?